# post 2 forms in one view

Tags: php, yii

i have problems with duplication of pk, and only users model is saved then the rest will 0 value,

need help guys. thanks in advance

**Model: Student** [edited]

```
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('studentid', 'required'),
        array('studentid', 'unique'),
        array('studentid, year, cellphonenumber', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('lastname, firstname, middlename, course, email', 'length', 'max'=>32),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('studentid, lastname, firstname, middlename, course, year, cellphonenumber, email', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}

/**
 * @return array relational rules.
 */
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(

    );
}

/**
 * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
        'studentid' => 'Studentid',
        'lastname' => 'Lastname',
        'firstname' => 'Firstname',
        'middlename' => 'Middlename',
        'course' => 'Course',
        'year' => 'Year',
        'cellphonenumber' => 'Cellphonenumber',
        'email' => 'Email',
    );
}

/**
 * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
 *
 * Typical usecase:
 * - Initialize the model fields with values from filter form.
 * - Execute this method to get CActiveDataProvider instance which will filter
 * models according to data in model fields.
 * - Pass data provider to CGridView, CListView or any similar widget.
 *
 * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models
 * based on the search/filter conditions.
 */
public function search()
{
    // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('studentid',$this->studentid);
    $criteria->compare('lastname',$this->lastname,true);
    $criteria->compare('firstname',$this->firstname,true);
    $criteria->compare('middlename',$this->middlename,true);
    $criteria->compare('course',$this->course,true);
    $criteria->compare('year',$this->year);
    $criteria->compare('cellphonenumber',$this->cellphonenumber);
    $criteria->compare('email',$this->email,true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}

/**
 * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
 * Please note that you should have this exact method in all your CActiveRecord descendants!
 * @param string $className active record class name.
 * @return Student the static model class
 */
public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
{
    return parent::model($className);
}
```

}

**Controller:**

public function actionCreateUsers()
    {

```
    $vm = (object) array(); 
    $vm->Users=new Users;
    $vm->Student=new Student;
    $vm->Instructor=new Instructor;
    $holder;

    // $model=new Users;
    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Users']))
    {
        $vm->Users->attributes=$_POST['Users'];
        $vm->Users->save();
            if(isset($_POST['Student']))
                {
                $vm->Student->attributes=$_POST['Student'];
                $vm->Student->studentid = $vm->Users->username;
                    if($vm->Student->save())
                        $vm->Student->unsetAttributes();
                }
            if(isset($_POST['Instructor']))
                {
                $vm->Instructor->attributes=$_POST['Instructor'];
                $vm->Instructor->instructorid = $vm->Users->username;
                    if($vm->Instructor->save())
                        $vm->Instructor->unsetAttributes();
                }
            else {
                return false;
                }
    }

            // echo 'saved';
            // $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->username));

    $vm->Users->unsetAttributes();
    $vm->Student->unsetAttributes();
    $vm->Instructor->unsetAttributes();
    $this->render('users',array(
        'vm'=>$vm,
    ));
}
```

**View:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which variables do not have the expected values? Which values are expected?

Comment: when i click save, the value of (lastname,firstname,middlename,cellphone,email) is not save.

Comment: Is this Yii 1, right?

Comment: Yes it is, Yii 1.1

Comment: all these fields are in same user model or different??

Comment: Can you show us the code of your models? do you have a virtual attribute?

Comment: if you have defined virtual attributes then put them in safe in rules of define some rules for them

Comment: the fields are in other models

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please provide the code

As you said that one `model` is saving but others are not. This may be the issue of `rules` define in `model`.

Try to `getErrors()` if model doesn't save

```
$vm = (object) array(); 
    $vm->Users=new Users;
    $vm->Student=new Student;
    $vm->Instructor=new Instructor;
    $holder;

    // $model=new Users;
    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Users']))
    {
        $vm->Users->attributes=$_POST['Users'];
        $vm->Users->save();
            if(isset($_POST['Student']))
                {
                $vm->Student->attributes=$_POST['Student'];
                $vm->Student->studentid = $vm->Users->username;
                    if($vm->Student->save())
                        $vm->Student->unsetAttributes();
                      else{
                           print_r($vm->Student->getErrors());die;// to get errors
                             }

                }
            if(isset($_POST['Instructor']))
                {
                $vm->Instructor->attributes=$_POST['Instructor'];
                $vm->Instructor->instructorid = $vm->Users->username;
                    if($vm->Instructor->save())
                        $vm->Instructor->unsetAttributes();
                     else{
                           print_r($vm->Instructor->getErrors());die;// to get errors
                             }
                }
            else {
                return false;
                }
    }

            // echo 'saved';
            // $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->username));

    $vm->Users->unsetAttributes();
    $vm->Student->unsetAttributes();
    $vm->Instructor->unsetAttributes();
    $this->render('users',array(
        'vm'=>$vm,
    ));
}
```

Comment: Array ( [studentid] => Array ( [0] => Studentid "12333" has already been taken. ) ) this error

Comment: So your student id in database is primary autoincrement is or not if yes then remove that as autoincrement. If you want same syudent id to insert in db

Answer (score 0):

In order to debug, remember you can add:

```
if($vm->Student->save()) {
  $vm->Student->unsetAttributes();
} else {
  var_dump($vm->getErrors());
  die;
}
```

Same for instructors. Hope it helps

Comment: if($vm->Student->save()) {
  $vm->Student->unsetAttributes();
} else {
  var_dump($vm->getErrors());
  die;
}

the else statement is not working?
im sorry i am newbie, need this to work for my thesis

Comment: If the flow is not getting to the "else" if means save returned true. If it is not saving, it means you have not set your rules correctly, can you share your models?

Comment: Can you explain me how this form works? I see you are setting studentid from username, shouldnt be from id?